# why this syntax List.Add(item);{ //some code }

Tags: c#

I was reading [this sample code](http://blog.devarchive.net/2013/03/fast-dijkstras-algorithm-inside-ms-sql.html) and found this syntax when adding a item to a `List`

```
myList.Add(item);
{
   //some code
}
```

I'm wondering why this is used and what is the interest?

In the linked sample code the concerned class is  `Graph` in the `CreateEdge` method here is an extract of that method:

```
edge.SourceVertex.Neighbours.Add(edge.TargetVertex);
{
    var key = GetKey(edge.SourceVertex.ID, edge.TargetVertex.ID);
    if (!mEdges.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        mEdges.Add(key, edge);
    }
    else if (mEdges[key].Cost > edge.Cost)
    {
        mEdges[key] = edge;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just a block after the call. It's unusual on its own though - can you link to the sample code?

Comment: Are you sure you copy-pasted that correctly? If so, there's really not much to say. It's just a code block, that's meant to be executed afterwards.

Comment: have you  correctly posted the sample code ???????

Comment: I write a code like that when I don't want to reuse temporary values.

Comment: Thanks to all people, I now know this is a block of code that has nothing to do with the `List` itself!

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for your comment, I linked the sample code as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned the statement "`myList.Add(item);`" and Branch"{ }" is different meaning.we
should not relate with each other.any how the branch inside code will not accessible from
 outside code.only that case branch is use full.we can say information hiding in side the 
method.I hope this will helpfull for you.

```
var tag = new Tag()
   {
    Id=1
   };

var tags = new List<Tag>();

tags.Add(tag);
   {
    var t = tag; `//scope of t only accessible inside the branch.`
   }

tags.Add(t);`//This will cause error.`
```

In above case t will not accessible from the outside of the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two separate statements.

```
myList.Add(item);  // Adds a new item to a list.

{
    // some code that always run (no conditional statement ("if", "while", etc.))
}
```

You'd expect to usually see it with a conditional:

```
if (someVariable = someValue)
{
    // some code
}
```

Or as an object initializer for the item being added to the list:

```
myList.Add(new Item
    {
        somePropertyInItem = 5;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It does nothing.

`{` and `}` define a scope. It is completely valid to have a dangling scope. It is separate to the line that adds to the list.

Answer (score 1):

`{` and `}` has nothing to do with `mylist.Add(item);`, because of `;` symbol at the end. (Btw, I don't know myself the right name for it, is it *blank operator* or what?). It is a separator (of commands? operands?) and sometimes could be used on it's own as a sort of `nop` (do nothing), to example, if cycles where all needed is already performed in the cycle condition.

If it would be

```
mylist.Add(item)
{
}
```

then they would be related (though this is a syntax error), as Grand Winney answered, it is more likely to see this with operators like `if`, `switch`,`while`, to instantiate class, etc. Which is possibly missing (book printing error?).

As Simon Whitehead answered, `{` and `}` will define a scope. Which, in fact, can be useful in the code by its own (though peoples use it very rarely).

One example of using scopes on their own is to have even more *local* variables (hidden inside scopes).

```
{
    var i = 123;
    // do something with i
}

{
    var i = 123; // can be declared without error
    // do something with i
}

// error
i++;
```